# How to replace sub-query code as alias in My SQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I'd like to know how to shorten sub-query code as alias. I have two data table, `data1` and `data2`. In `data1`, there are data of Yield and Biomass. In `data2`, there is data of Height.

This is my code.

```
SELECT *,

  (SELECT Height
   FROM data2
   WHERE data1.ID = data2.ID) AS Height,
       round(avg(data1.Yield), 1) AS Avg_Yield,
       round(avg(data1.Biomass), 1) AS Avg_Biomass,
       round(avg(
                   (SELECT Height
                    FROM data2
                    WHERE data1.ID = data2.ID)), 1) AS Avg_Height
FROM data1
WHERE
    (SELECT Height
     FROM data2
     WHERE data1.ID = data2.ID) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY data1.Fertilizer,
         data1.Genotype;
```

[image]

It makes complicated every time using the sub-query code, `select Height from data2 where data1.ID = data2.ID`

Could you tell me how to replace this code as alias (or shortened code)? I thought I already put an alias when coding `select *, (select Height from data2 where data1.ID = data2.ID) as Height` but it does not work when replacing the sub-query code as Height.

How can I simplify the above code?

Always many thanks!!

---

This is data1

```
CREATE TABLE data1
    (`Plot_No` int, `Fertilizer` varchar(7), `Rep` varchar(3), `Genotype` varchar(3), 
    `Yield` int, `Biomass` int, `ID` varchar(15));
    
INSERT INTO data1
    (`Plot_No`, `Fertilizer`, `Rep`, `Genotype`, `Yield`, `Biomass`, `ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Control', 'I', 'CV1', 1190, 1150, '1ControlICV1'),
    (2, 'Control', 'I', 'CV2', 1240, 1220, '2ControlICV2'),
    (3, 'Control', 'I', 'CV3', 1240, 1230, '3ControlICV3'),
    (4, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV1', 980, 1090, '4FastICV1'),
    (5, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV2', 950, 1180, '5FastICV2'),
    (6, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV3', 1030, 1200, '6FastICV3'),
    (7, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV1', 1580, 1170, '7SlowICV1'),
    (8, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV2', 1580, 1180, '8SlowICV2'),
    (9, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV3', 1580, 1230, '9SlowICV3'),
    (10, 'Control', 'II', 'CV1', 1180, 1180, '10ControlIICV1'),
    (11, 'Control', 'II', 'CV2', 1140, 1180, '11ControlIICV2'),
    (12, 'Control', 'II', 'CV3', 1130, 1230, '12ControlIICV3'),
    (13, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV1', 910, 1270, '13FastIICV1'),
    (14, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV2', 950, 1240, '14FastIICV2'),
    (15, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV3', 880, 1280, '15FastIICV3'),
    (16, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV1', 1660, 1130, '16SlowIICV1'),
    (17, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV2', 1560, 1240, '17SlowIICV2'),
    (18, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV3', 1650, 1250, '18SlowIICV3'),
    (19, 'Control', 'III', 'CV1', 1210, 1058, '19ControlIIICV1'),
    (20, 'Control', 'III', 'CV2', 1310, 1200, '20ControlIIICV2'),
    (21, 'Control', 'III', 'CV3', 1270, 1310, '21ControlIIICV3'),
    (22, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV1', 980, 1380, '22FastIIICV1'),
    (23, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV2', 950, 1250, '23FastIIICV2'),
    (24, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV3', 960, 1230, '24FastIIICV3'),
    (25, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV1', 1540, 1320, '25SlowIIICV1'),
    (26, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV2', 1580, 1220, '26SlowIIICV2'),
    (27, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV3', 1500, 1290, '27SlowIIICV3');
```

This is data2

```
CREATE TABLE data2
    (`Plot_No` int, `Fertilizer` varchar(7), `Block` varchar(3), 
    `Genotype` varchar(3), `ID` varchar(15), `Height` varchar(4), 
    `Planting` datetime);
    
INSERT INTO data2
    (`Plot_No`, `Fertilizer`, `Block`, `Genotype`, `ID`, `Height`, `Planting`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Control', 'I', 'CV1', '1ControlICV1', '87', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (4, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV1', '4FastICV1', NULL, '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (7, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV1', '7SlowICV1', '79', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (10, 'Control', 'II', 'CV1', '10ControlIICV1', '93', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (13, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV1', '13FastIICV1', '92', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (16, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV1', '16SlowIICV1', '86', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (19, 'Control', 'III', 'CV1', '19ControlIIICV1', '84', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (22, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV1', '22FastIIICV1', '85', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (25, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV1', '25SlowIIICV1', '77', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (2, 'Control', 'I', 'CV2', '2ControlICV2', '88', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (5, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV2', '5FastICV2', '87', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (8, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV2', '8SlowICV2', '85', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (11, 'Control', 'II', 'CV2', '11ControlIICV2', '97', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (14, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV2', '14FastIICV2', NULL, '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (17, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV2', '17SlowIICV2', '87', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (20, 'Control', 'III', 'CV2', '20ControlIIICV2', '96', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (23, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV2', '23FastIIICV2', NULL, '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (26, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV2', '26SlowIIICV2', '89', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (3, 'Control', 'I', 'CV3', '3ControlICV3', '89', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (6, 'Fast', 'I', 'CV3', '6FastICV3', '78', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (9, 'Slow', 'I', 'CV3', '9SlowICV3', '87', '2022-02-12 09:00:00'),
    (12, 'Control', 'II', 'CV3', '12ControlIICV3', '88', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (15, 'Fast', 'II', 'CV3', '15FastIICV3', '81', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (18, 'Slow', 'II', 'CV3', '18SlowIICV3', '96', '2022-02-11 09:00:00'),
    (21, 'Control', 'III', 'CV3', '21ControlIIICV3', '77', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (24, 'Fast', 'III', 'CV3', '24FastIIICV3', '68', '2022-02-10 09:00:00'),
    (27, 'Slow', 'III', 'CV3', '27SlowIIICV3', NULL, '2022-02-10 09:00:00');
```

Comment: can you post the table creates an some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ . And which MyQL / MariaDB you are using

Comment: You can replace the correlated subquery with a join, but it is not going to be much shorter in terms of code. Not to mention the fact that the length of code does not imply code complexity, nor performance.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I added the data1 and data2. I use My SQL version 8.0.20. Thanks!!

Comment: You need to be mindful of the impact of group by and the use of aggregate functions.

Comment: Try this query. i cant answer: SELECT
      d1.*
    , d2.Height AS Height
    , round(AVG(d1.Yield), 1) AS Avg_Yield
    , round(AVG(d1.Biomass), 1) AS Avg_Biomass,
       round(AVG(d2.Height), 1) AS Avg_Height
FROM data1 d1
INNER JOIN data2 d2  ON d1.id = d2.id AND d2.Height IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d1.Fertilizer,
         d1.Genotype;

Comment: @Jin.W.Kim - if my query works for you, you must add an index on some columns  like data2.id ,... to speed up your query

Comment: @Shadow - I don't see the relevance of the "dup".

Comment: @Jin.W.Kim - `Height` looks numeric; perhaps it should be `SMALLINT` instead of `VARCHAR(4)`?

Comment: @BerndBuffen - I suggest this for `d1`: `INDEX(Genotype, Fertilizer)`

Comment: @Jin.W.Kim - Every table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @RickJames the question was how to shorten the query. The dupe shows how to rewrite a correlated subquery in the select lust as join.

Comment: @Shadow - the dup looks like two ways to "pivot"; the Question looks like something different.

Comment: @RickJames not sure what you mean by pivoting, there is no aggregation in the duplicate question. This question is explicitly about writing the correlated subquery in a different way. The different way is to use joins, which is demonstrated in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments!! What I wanted to know was how to shorten the sub query codes. It was annoying every time to designate "Primary and Foreign Key" to activate JOIN code. So I tried to use sub-query, but the sub-query code was so long, so I wanted to know how to put alias in such a sub-query code. Thank you for your helps!!!